# How to flatten stamp annotations in a pdf using iText or PdfBox?

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdfbox, itext7

I have a document with a stamp annotation added to it, I can flatten the acroform present in the pdf, but this doesn't flatten the stamp annotations present in the pdf. I'm attaching the normal pdf with stamp and acroform flattened pdf.

I would like to flatten the annotations because if you open the flattened pdf in the Preview application of MAC, we can edit the pdf like moving the annotations and deleting them. I would like to avoid those. So if I can flatten the annotations in the pdf along with form fields, then I guess the movement of annotations will be restricted in the Preview application.

This is the code I have used to add the stamp:

```
PdfReader reader1 = new PdfReader(file);
ByteArrayOutputStream mos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfDocument docc = new PdfDocument(reader1, new PdfWriter(mos),new StampingProperties().useAppendMode());
String filePath = "rectangle.png";
ImageData img = ImageDataFactory.create(filePath);
Rectangle rect=null;
float w = img.getWidth();
float h = img.getHeight();
rect = new Rectangle(0,0,250,400);
PdfFormXObject xObj = new PdfFormXObject(new Rectangle(w,h));
PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(xObj, docc);
canvas.addImageAt(img,0,0,false);
PdfStampAnnotation stamp = new PdfStampAnnotation(rect);
stamp.setNormalAppearance(xObj.getPdfObject());
docc.getPage(1).addAnnotation(stamp);

docc.close();

file = new File("Annotation Added.pdf");
FileOutputStream fout1 = new FileOutputStream(file);
fout1.write(mos.toByteArray());
fout1.close();
```

These are the files :

[PDF Before flattening with stamp annotation](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nP1W5H2-HPra8JKPrh9TvFR5wS7f1aBL/view?usp=sharing)

[PDF After flattening](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1z2piiIeOmylZnblqCBNMUtrlSmJf4kWT/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @mkl, whether my requirement possible?

Comment: As far as I know there are no highlevel methods in iText 7 for flattening arbitrary annotations yet, only for flattening widget annotations (form fields). It should be possible, though, to flatten other annotations in a similar manner with iText 7. Thus, a solution would be to copy that form field flattening code and adapt it for other annotation types.

Comment: @mkl I can try that. Can you provide me any POC of that?, 
and also In iText 5.5.9 version there is a method called setAnnotationFlattening (https://javadoc.io/doc/com.itextpdf/itextpdf/5.5.9/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfStamper.html#setAnnotationFlattening-boolean-) Isn't there any equivalent method in the current version of iText?

Comment: Have a look at the iText forms class [`PdfAcroForm`](https://github.com/itext/itext7/blob/develop/forms/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/forms/PdfAcroForm.java). It has a method `flattenFields` to flatten the widget annotations of form fields. you can take this code as inspiration for a flattener of arbitrary annotations (at least those that bring along an appearance stream).

Comment: will try it and get back if any issue arises. Anything on setAnnotationFlattening ?

Comment: *"Anything on setAnnotationFlattening ?"* - As far as I can see that functionality has not been ported to iText 7.